# How can I solve an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Tags: android, media-player

**I'm very new to android programming and I'm trying to solve an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error. When I start my media player all three songs will play but once their complete the app will crash.  The stop button will work but not the pause.Please help I have exhausted all that I can to get understanding.  Please help** 
    **This is the play method**

```
public void play() {
tracks[0] = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.blipotron;
tracks[1] = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.funk_game;
tracks[2] = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.poofy_reel;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),   
Uri.parse(tracks[currentTrack]));
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

**This is the stop and pause methods**

```
public void stopPlayer(){
    if (container == STARTED)
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}

public void pausePlayer(){
    if (container == STARTED) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        container = PAUSED;
    }
}

 **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3 at
 **onCompletion(TestPlayerMainActivity.java:167)**
**Line 167 is mp = Mediaplayer.create(this, Uri.parse(tracks[currentTrack)**
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
   // mp.release();
   if (currentTrack < tracks.length ) {
       currentTrack++;
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(tracks[currentTrack]));
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
       container = PREPARED;
       mp.start();
       container = STARTED;

         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hello Frank I have been searching for an answer in hope that it would address this issue.  But unfortunately I have not been able to find anything relatable.  Which is why I posted my code in hopes that someone could help me with the specifics of my issue.  And to hopefully give me a little more understanding  how to solve my problem.  Please assist me.

Comment: Change "if (currentTrack < tracks.length )" for "if (currentTrack < tracks.length -1 )". Because if "tracks.length"= 3 and "currentTrack"= 2, you increment "currentTrack" and try to access "tracks[3]" that throw exception (array index begin by 0, so can only access tracks[0], tracks[1], tracks[2])

Comment: Bubu thank you so very much that simple fix stopped my little app from crashing.  You were so helpful.  And I am so thankful.